# Center from CSS a <li>

Tags: html, css, html-lists, center

I have a question.
I want to center a menu with a `<li>` tag, and I have two buttons.

```
.subiectele-zilei {
    width:100%;
    padding-left: 25px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    margin-top:2px;

    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
.subiectele-zilei li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#008cff;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:14px;
}
.subiectele-zilei li a {
    background: #ffffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #e5e6e6 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e6e6));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e6e6 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e6e6 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e6e6 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e6e6 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e6e6',GradientType=0 );
    border-radius:100px;
    padding:2px 15px 3px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 0 #b8b8b8, inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
    display:block;
    margin-top:11px;
    margin-right:8px;
    float:center;
    margin-left:55px;

}
```

And with `<li> TEXT</li>` I put on the center of 100% width.

Comment: post your html too?

Answer (score 0):

Yea, here:

HTML

```
<div class="subiectele-zilei">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="https://observatorulnational.ro/cazul-comisarului-berbeceanu/">CAZUL COMISARULUI BERBECEANU</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://observatorulnational.ro/observatorul-national-live/">OBSERVATORUL NA&#x21a;IONAL LIVE</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
```